# Simple HTTP server which need to discard clients requests and support compression

Tags: c, internet-explorer, http, firefox

I need to write a simple HTTP server for sending diagnostic about with the remaining of my application. So I've first tried this simple example:

```
/* Simple HTTP server which discard the client request. Please record this file in ISO-8859-15 to get proper results */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#define CHUNK 8388608
#include <unistd.h>

/*****************************************************************************
 * Crée et envoi la réponse au client
 *****************************************************************************/
void * reponse(int newsockfd)
{
    char * buffer=calloc(sizeof(char),5890);
    sprintf(buffer,"<!DOCTYPE html>\n\
<html>\n\
<head>\n\
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO8859-15\">\n\
    <title color=\"white\">ACCÈS INTERDIT!</title>\n\
    <script>\n\
        function launchFullscreen() {\n\
            if(document.body.requestFullscreen) {\n\
                document.body.requestFullscreen();\n\
            } else if(document.body.mozRequestFullScreen) {\n\
                document.body.mozRequestFullScreen();\n\
            } else if(document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen) {\n\
                document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen();\n\
            } else if(document.body.msRequestFullscreen) {\n\
                document.body.msRequestFullscreen();\n\
            }\n\
        }\n\
    \n\
    </script>\n\

    </head>\n\
\n\
    <body align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" >\n\
        <button onclick=\"launchFullscreen();\">ACCÈS INTERDIT!</button>\n\
    </body>\n\
</html>\r\n\0");
    size_t inputLen = strlen(buffer);
    uLong maxCompressLen = compressBound(inputLen);
    char * destbuffer=calloc(sizeof(char),maxCompressLen);
    compress2(destbuffer,&maxCompressLen,buffer,inputLen,Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
    memset(buffer,0,(unsigned int)maxCompressLen+1);
    sprintf( buffer, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\
Vary: Accept-Encoding\n\
Content-Length: %ld\n\
Connection: close\n\
Content-encoding: deflate\n\
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-15\n\
Content-language: fr\n\
X-Powered-By: GCC 4.8.1 avec -flto -mtune=native et -Ofast!\n\
Server: Serveur avec easter-egg servant à faire la différence entre une page bloqué et une connection internet qui ne marche pas\n\
\r\n",maxCompressLen);
    memcpy( buffer+359, destbuffer, maxCompressLen);
    write(newsockfd,buffer,359+maxCompressLen);
    free(buffer);
    free(destbuffer);
    close(newsockfd);
}

void main()
{
    close(0);close(1);close(2); // close stderr stdin stdout
    pthread_t parallel;
    struct  sockaddr_in6 client_address, server_address;
    int newsockfd,clilen=sizeof(client_address),server_handle=socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (server_handle < 0)
        perror("Unable to create socket.");
    server_address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server_address.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    server_address.sin6_port = 0x5000; // port 80
    if ( bind(server_handle, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof( server_address )) < 0)
        perror("Unable to bind.");
    listen(server_handle,0xF);


    struct passwd *pass;
    struct group *grp;
    /* lookup the uid/gid for the given user and group name */
    if ((pass = getpwnam("nobody")) == NULL) {
    perror("Can't find username!\n");
    exit(1);
    }    
    if ((grp = getgrnam("nogroup")) == NULL) {
        perror("Can't fine groupname!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* drop root */
    if (setgid(grp->gr_gid) == -1) {
        perror("Couldn't change groupid");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (setuid(pass->pw_uid) == -1) {
        perror("Couldn't change userid");
        exit(1);
    }
    endpwent();
    endgrent();
Boucle:;
        newsockfd=accept(server_handle, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &clilen);
        pthread_create(&parallel,NULL,reponse,(void *)newsockfd);
    goto Boucle;
}
```

The main problem is that IE and firefox complain about connection resets and don't display it. Presto based version of opera and blink/webkit based browsers don't suffer of this problem...

So I'm thinking about an error in the HTTP protocol.

**Update**:It seems there's also a small memory leak in my code...

Comment: Aren't http lines terminated by `"\r\n"` ?

Comment: What is this `close(0);close(1);close(2);` for?

Comment: @alk : No, `\r\n` is only the separation beetween the header and the body of the request. The remaining in the body have the same behaviour of an html file. `close(0);close(1);close(2);` is a part for daemonizing the process.

Comment: **Each** request-/response-header line shall be terminated by a `"\r\n"`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message

Comment: @alk : I'm reading "The Status-Line and headers" . My response have only one HTTP header, but It's OK for the status line and it changed nothing...

Comment: Uhmm .. ok, might be I overinterpreted this ... :-)

Comment: @alk : I'm starting wondering if firefox and IE support only keep-alive connections which I have no idea on how to implement them...

Comment: You might like to add an empty line (`"\r\n"`) after the header.

Comment: @alk : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49251/discussion-between-user2284570-and-alk

Comment: I cannot access the chat from here. Sry.

Comment: Your code just adds **one** `\r\n` after the header. I was mentioning an **addtional, second** `\r\n` serving as an empty line.

Comment: @alk : You need an empty line after the header, not a double CR/LF. Again please read my code: I'm using `\n\r\n`.

Comment: The spex say "*<header>CRLFCRLF*" which would translate to: `"... header text\r\n\r\n"`: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

Comment: @alk : Not needed at all. I finally solved my problem without needing this...